# How to configure a real domain name for sender address

Tags: linux, php, configuration, sendmail

I tried to sending out an email using php `mail()` function but it failed somehow, complaining that a real domain name is required. The following is observed in the maillog:

> sendmail 4984 r25984: from=apache, size=273, class=0, nrcpts=1,
>   msgid=<201.r25@localhost.localdomain>, relay=apache@localhost
>   sendmail 4985 r25985: ruleset=check_mail,
>   arg1=, relay=mydomain.com [127.0.0.1],
>   reject=553 5.5.4 ... Real domain name
>   required for sender address
>  sendmail 4984 r25984:
>   to=external@server.com, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:01,
>   xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30273, relay=[127.0.0.1]
>   [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.6.0, stat=Data format error
>  sendmail 4984
>   r25984: r25984: DSN: Data format error

cron is able to send email to external@server.com whenever there is a problem with logrotate. I am not sure why php is unable to do so. I tried making changes to the default configuration in `sendmail.mc with the following:

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`mydomain.com')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_entire_domain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(mycom)dnl
```

But, it doesn't seem to have any effect. The header from address in php mail function has already been set. I have also ensured that SELinux `httpd_can_sendmail` is enabled. What else to I need to do to get the mail delivered?

Comment: You edited the `sendmail.mc`, changed the lines `localhost.localdomain` and `localhost` to something meaningful and compiled the mc file into `sendmail.cf`?

Comment: @fboaventura, no, I uncommented the two lines by removing `dnl` in front of them.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your php script, where you are invoking `mail()`?  And, the `sendmail.mc` isn't the proper configuration file, this file must be compiled into `sendmail.cf` using the `m4`.

Comment: @fboaventura, thanks, I know that regarding the compilation requirement, I am able to get it work now. See my answer below. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I have just solved it. I have the following in */etc/hosts*:

```
127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.com test.mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 cdn.mycdn.com
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost myserver.com
```

What I need is to place myserver.com in front of the line with `localhost.localdomain` so that *sendmail* will think that it is using a real domain to send out the email.

Comment: You  could definately accept your own answer is that was the solution ... As a sidenote, it is usually `/etc/hosts` (with an "s"), other than that: good answer!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, on Ubuntu 16.04 on an AWS instance, what was needed was to add to `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc`:

```
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `mydomainname.com')dnl
```

on a line before the `MAILER_DEFINITIONS` line toward the end of the file, AND add the same line to the end of `/etc/mail/submit.mc`. Then type `sudo su` for root permissions, and compile to config with:

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf
m4 submit.mc > submit.cf
```

...then `exit` sudo. Finally, `sudo service sendmail restart` to restart sendmail, and from thereon emails were appearing as sent from the domain name. None of the other FEATURE or MASQUERADE commands were required, nor an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Instead of running these `m4` commands by hand you can run `make` that does them for you (among other things).

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure, in your scripts, the headers of your email to have `From: sender@domain.com`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this has already been set in headers.

Answer (score 1):

In your `sendmail.mc` add:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
Djmyserver.com
```

Recompile `sendmail.cf`, restart sendmail and you should be OK