# Why does sendmail changes the FROM domain and how to configure the proper one?

Tags: linux, centos, smtp, sendmail, centos7

I installed Jenkins and configured it to send emails as being sent from "jenkins@jenkins.example.com" but the address is always changed when email is being sent and I receive the mail as being sent from "jenkins@default.vps.example.com".

I've installed Sendmail and Jenkins is configured to use 127.0.0.1 as mail server.

Any idea why Sendmail replaces the FROM domain when email is being sent?

The hostname of the server is properly set (when I run `hostname` I do get "jenkins.example.com").

Same way if I send an email from command line `echo "This is the body" | mail -s "Subject" u@d.com`

From where does it take this `default.vps.example.com` domain? Where is this default domain configurable?

LE: in my sendmail.mc I have `define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `jenkins.domain.com')dnl` and I generated the sendmail.cf file `m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf` and restarted sendmail. Still doesn't work.

LE2:

```
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> canonify           input: jenkins @ jenkins . example . com
Canonify2          input: jenkins < @ jenkins . example . com >
dns_getcanonname(jenkins.example.com, trymx=1)
dns_getcanonname: trying jenkins.example.com. (AAAA)
    YES
dns_getcanonname: trying default.vps.example.com. (AAAA)
    NO: errno=0, h_errno=4
dns_getcanonname: trying default.vps.example.com. (A)
    YES
dns_getcanonname: default.vps.example.com
Canonify2        returns: jenkins < @ default . vps . example . com . >
canonify         returns: jenkins < @ default . vps . example . com . >
>
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/645839/37681) is of use.

Comment: See my edit. Already did this and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite likely your sendmail replaces names with DNS `CNAME` record (DNS alias) with "true names".

As root execute `echo '3 jenkins@jenkins.example.com' | sendmail -d8.20 -bt`
It should show you DNS queries during email address preprocessing (by rule set `3`).

http://cr.yp.to/im/cname.html

> D. J. Bernstein
> **CNAME records in mail**
> [RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) prohibited all use of ``nicknames or aliases'' in domain names in SMTP requests. [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) specifically prohibited DNS aliases (domains with CNAME records) in MAIL and RCPT requests.
> sendmail accepts a domain with a CNAME record. It replaces the domain with the CNAME value before using it in RCPT, unless it is acting as a dumb client. Similar comments apply to qmail and other mailers.

Comment: I updated my question with the output. So it looks like for jenkins.example.com it only finds (AAAA) while for the default/initial hostname default.vps.example.com it finds both (AAAA) and (A) and in the end it decides to use default . vps . example . com. Any idea why?

Comment: So it must be as you said that it replaces the CNAME with the "true" default name... Any idea what can be done to stop it from doing this? Or to configure it to use the CNAME instead?

Comment: It trivial to stop YOUR sendmail to replace CNAMEs with "real names" [see DontExapndCnames] but sendmails/MTAs beyond your control will do it.